# Solidify thickness doesn't correspond to specified scale

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm Having trouble with setting the thickness applied by solidify. The selected block is 15 by 28 cm (single mesh sides) and the thickness of solidify is set to 3mm (pointing inwards). Checking off even thickness makes it even worse. I was using the function in a different object earlier today and it worked just fine. Is there something I'm missing or is this just a bug?

Feel free to treat me like an idiot, I've literally started using blender yesterday :)

[image: Incorrect thickness]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your object has uneven scale

Apply the scale to your object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*

Comment: How can I animate the scale of the solid so that the thickness is proportionate?

Comment: You can't. Use shapekeys to animate its shape instead