# Solidify thickness doesn't correspond to specified scale although scale of object is applied

Tags: modifiers, scale

I have the same problems as described in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74816/solidify-thickness-doesnt-correspond-to-specified-scale) thread, but the object to which I'm trying to apply "solidify" to has it proportions all set to "1"

What is causing this ?

Comment: To clarify: by proportions you mean scale?  Suggest adding a screenshot.

Comment: @batFinger yes, I mean scale. I already figured it out, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately after posting this question, I realised my problem.
Hopefully it might help someone else, in the future (or in the past)

The object was parented to a dummy object (this project is full of it, I think I didn't import this drawing the right way), which wasn't scaled properly, affecting the scale of the child-object.

I remember now that it appeared strange to me that the object (a technical drawing of a MAN NG272 Public Transport Bus, wasn't scaled properly, 
but as an afterthought I think it was, but the empty (empties) wasn't (weren't).

So, instead of removing the dummy parents, I just scaled the whole drawing  to what I thought was right, hence a number of problems later on ...

So the actual solution was to remove the parent of the object, keeping the transform (Alt-P) and then re-apply the scale, after which the solidify parameter works as expected.